# Get value of same cell from multiple sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'd like to get the value of cell A1 from multiple tabs in my sheet.  I attempted to use `INDIRECT`, only to be reminded that it wouldn't work in an `ARRAYFORMULA`.  Is there some sort of "makeshifty" formula that would do the same thing?

This is what I originally attempted:

```
 =ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),INDIRECT(A2:A&"!A1"),))
```

Column A is a select list of the tab names in my sheet.  So the first instance works, but of course, it doesn't populate down the column as I had hoped.  I realize I can just copy the formula down the column, but some type of an `ARRAYFORMULA` would be ideal as I add rows to the list.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20631477), but don't see how I could apply it to my situation.

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21247504/11388717), but thought since it's 2.5 years old, maybe someone has discovered a clever way to avoid the *drag* of copying.

Comment: there is script if you interested (?)

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You need to do this with a script or by using the drag method - `INDIRECT` uses a string reference and so can't be used with an array.*

#### More Information:

Unfortunately for the user of `INDIRECT` with `ARRAYFORMULA`, a discovery of a clever method isn't the issue - the limitation of what can be done with only formulae that is the root of this problem.

#### Setting up a custom function:

From the Tools > Script editor menu item, you can create scripts. An example custom formula that you could use would be as follows:

```js
function ARRAYINDIRECT(input) {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  return input.reduce(function(array, el) {
    if (el[0]) array.push(el[0])
    return array;
  }, []).map(x => ss.getSheetByName(x).getRange("A1").getValue());
}
```

Make sure to then save the script with the save icon.

In your Sheet you can then call this custom formula as so:

```
=ARRAYINDIRECT(A2:A)
```

**Rundown of the function:**

- Takes the input range from where the formula is called - in this case `A2:A`
- Reduces the input to remove all cells that are empty
- Maps the name of the sheet which is stored in the cell to the value in `A1` of the sheet it references
- Returns an array to output

#### References:

- [JavaScript Array reduce() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp)
- [INDIRECT - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)