# Easiest way to query multiple sheets that are named by year, for all time?

Tags: google-sheets

I use a big nasty formula to query multiple sheets in the same Google Sheet document named according to year (2020, 2019, 2018, etc...) to sum up a total value. Because I need to query a filtered range in a complex way, I've figured out the best way to do this without running into other troubleshooting issues is to SUM multiple queries like so:

> =SUM(
> IFERROR(QUERY(FILTER({EOMONTH(INDIRECT("'"&**TO_TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()))**&"'!A1:A"&ROWS(INDIRECT("'"&**TO_TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()))**&"'!K2:K"))), 0),INDIRECT("'"&**TO_TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()))**&"'!K2:K")}, [filter conditions]), "select Col2 label Col2' ' ")),
> IFERROR(QUERY(FILTER({EOMONTH(INDIRECT("'"&**TO_TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()-365))**&"'!A1:A"&ROWS(INDIRECT("'"&**TO_TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()-365))**&"'!K2:K"))),0),INDIRECT("'"&**TO_TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()-365))**&"'!K2:K")}, [filter conditions]),
> "select Col2 label Col2' ' "))
> )

For some context, you can see the much larger IF formula that this SUM is meant to be nested into, in the "Example Matrix" tab of the sheet. My focus for this question is on the INDIRECT references, which I have been using to dynamically reference the most current year's sheet and the previous year's sheet.
The problem is, if I want to keep doing this for every sheet as the years go on, I have to manually add a whole other query into my SUM using INDIRECT("'"&TO_TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()-**730**))&"'!K2:K") and INDIRECT("'"&TO_TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()-**1095**))&"'!K2:K") and so on, and that is just not an option considering how many of them I would need to add to multiple formulas in multiple sheets.

Is there any way I can adapt this for simplicity or perhaps make it into a script to accomplish summing queries for all sheets that are named by year for all time?

Here's a copy of my Example Sheet:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b29gyEgCDwor_KJ6ACP2rxdvauOzacDI9FL2K-jgg5E/edit#gid=1652431688

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Usually an array formula would be a way to go in such case, but `INDIRECT` does not work inside array formulas. You could generate a formula text and copy paste it for execution once a year, or just get a formula for a 100 years with appropriate error handling, use it and forget about it for another 100 years.

Comment: @player0 I've added a link to the sheet, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Usually an array formula would be a way to go in such case, but `INDIRECT` does not work inside array formulas.

There are a few approaches using scripting like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62426494/279806).

Here I will describe another approach: **formula generation**. We'll get a string with the formula and manually place it in a cell. It would be nice to put it in an inverted `FORMULATEXT` function, but unfortunately there is no such function at the moment, so we'll just paste it manually.

### Step 1

Set the year limits (sheet names) in some cells. The first year of the period will be in `K22`, and the last will be in `M22`.

I set the period to from 2005 to 2040.

All the year numbers will e easily generated with `SEQUENCE`. If there were arbitrary names, a range of those names set manually would've been needed.

### Step 2

Write a formula generator for what you need. We just generate a string here, in that string will be a formula you would normally type manually. It is not hard, but there are a lot of repetition and it would be tedious to write it manually.

Here is the generator:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  "=SUM(
  FILTER(
    {
      " & JOIN(
            ";" & CHAR(10) & "      ",
            "IFERROR('" & SEQUENCE(M22 - K22 + 1, 1, K22, 1) & "'!D2:D, 0)"
          ) & "
    },
    ISNUMBER(
      {
        " & JOIN(
              ";" & CHAR(10) & "        ",
              "IFERROR('" & SEQUENCE(M22 - K22 + 1, 1, K22, 1) & "'!D2:D, 0)"
            ) & "
      }
    ),
    REGEXMATCH(
      {
        " & JOIN(
              ";" & CHAR(10) & "        ",
              "IFERROR('" & SEQUENCE(M22 - K22 + 1, 1, K22, 1) & "'!A2:A, 0)"
            ) & "
      },
      ""(?i)^TOTAL$""
    ),
    REGEXMATCH(
      {
        " & JOIN(
              ";" & CHAR(10) & "        ",
              "IFERROR('" & SEQUENCE(M22 - K22 + 1, 1, K22, 1) & "'!C2:C, 0)"
            ) & "
      },
      ""(?i)^"" & IF(F19 = ""Condition 1 Count"", ""Condition 1"", ""Condition 2"") & ""$""
    )
  )
)"
)
```

Compared to the original formula the resulting formula is heavily changed, simplified. For example there is no actual need for `INDIRECT` with this approach, `EOMONTH` wasn't used anywhere and so on.

### Step 3

Copy that result as text, remove enclosing quotes, replace double double quotes with single double quotes: `""` -> `"`.

Now we've got our formula to paste somewhere as we could've typed manually. Here is a part of it:

```
=SUM(
  FILTER(
    {
      IFERROR('2005'!F2:F, 0);
      IFERROR('2006'!F2:F, 0);
      ...
      IFERROR('2039'!F2:F, 0);
      IFERROR('2040'!F2:F, 0)
    },
    ISNUMBER(
      {
        IFERROR('2005'!F2:F, 0);
        IFERROR('2006'!F2:F, 0);
        ...
        IFERROR('2039'!F2:F, 0);
        IFERROR('2040'!F2:F, 0)
      }
    ),
    REGEXMATCH(
      {
        IFERROR('2005'!C2:C, 0);
        IFERROR('2006'!C2:C, 0);
        ...
        IFERROR('2039'!C2:C, 0);
        IFERROR('2040'!C2:C, 0)
      },
      "(?i)^TOTAL$"
    ),
    REGEXMATCH(
      {
        IFERROR('2005'!E2:E, 0);
        IFERROR('2006'!E2:E, 0);
        ...
        IFERROR('2039'!E2:E, 0);
        IFERROR('2040'!E2:E, 0)
      },
      "(?i)^" & IF(F19 = "Condition 1 Count", "Condition 1", "Condition 2") & "$"
    )
  )
)
```

### Step 4

Manually place this resulting formula into some cell.

It does what it supposed to do, dropdown reference works, non-existing sheets are tolerated.

There is no **2021** sheet for example, but when it will be crated there will be no need to change the formula, data from that new sheet will be used.

You'll need to repeat the process in two cases: the formula needs some change in logic or it is almost 2040 and you want to add another 50 years to the period. Still that process of generation is faster than making changes manually to the resulting monster.

---

A few notes on the original formula:

- `YEAR(TODAY() - 365)` ➡ `YEAR(TODAY()) - 1`. With your approach there will be an error because of leap years. Depends on the years number, but at the beginning of a year it will emerge for sure.
- `"select Col2 label Col2' ' "` ➡ `"select Col2 label Col2 ''"`. Do you really need a column with a header name `' '` (just a space)? I'm guessing it meant to be blank.
- No need for `TO_TEXT`.

Comment: Whoops, that NA was part of an IFERROR outside the SUM that I removed for simplicity. I've corrected it in the question. Taking a look at how this works now.

Comment: You did not copy 1st two formulas right. There are only strings.

Comment: @kishkin Generator is a solution of sorts, and integrates just fine inside a larger IF formula (in H32-34). You answered my original question so I've upvoted your solution but I'd like to keep the post open if anyone has alternatives, like making into a script or a shorter formula; because in the actual nested IF function I'm using I need to paste it into multiple places and add more conditions into the FILTER. I realize my problem is VERY complex and I'm doing my best to simplify it without removing important details... I very much appreciate your answer and learned a lot!!